# How to use return value of a function as condition of while that returns tuple in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, while-loop, conditional-statements

I was looking for something like this but I couldn't find so here it goes.

**Some background**

I use opencv to retrieve frames from a video file. Usually people do it in an endless loop like:

```
while (True):
    s, img = cv.read()
```

or

```
for i in xrange(10000): #just a big number
    s, img = cv.read()
```

now i want to retrieve all frames and quit the loop when there are no more frames. However my skills in python aren't strong enough to do what I want to do.

**What I want to know**

`read` function (or method, i don't know how they are called in python) returns a tuple: first represents success of the operation, and second represents the frame returned. I want to break the while loop when first element of the tuple is false. Having a C background, I thought maybe this would work:

```
while ((success, img = capture.read())[0]):
    #do sth with img
```

i thought this will break the loop when success is false. But it did not. Then i thought maybe this will work:

```
while ((success, img = capture.read()).success):
    #do sth with img
```

it also did not work. I don't want to do something like

```
while(True):
    s, i = capture.read()
    if (s == False):
        break
```

How can test the condition in `while`, not in an `if` which breaks if succesful?

Comment: Any reason why you don't want to do the last thing (which IMO is the correct way)?

Comment: I am with @RedBaron on this. I think your last excerpt is by far the clearest.

Comment: I think condition of `while` should be the loop condition.

Comment: It is worth noting that in python assignments cannot be made in the condition of a while or if statement.

Comment: By the way: people do *not* write `while(True)`, they write `while True`. There is no need for the parenthesis, they only increase the complexity of the expression.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the best way to think pythonic is to forget other languages

```
s = True
while s:
    s, i = capture.read()
    if s:
        do_some_stuff(i)
```

Comment: Personally, I prefer the OP's code (`while True` and `break`), especially if there is a non-trivial amount of code inside that `if s`. I find it slightly easier to grasp at a glance. However, that's just a personal preference.

Answer (score 20):

You could write a generator function.

```
def readframes(cv):
    while True:
        success, frame = cv.read()
        if success:
            yield frame
        else:
            return
```

This way you can loop through the frames with a for loop.

```
for frame in readframes(cv):
    do_something_with_frame(frame)
```

Comment: this looks neat at first glance :)

Comment: @HayriUğurKoltuk: So it's OK to break the endless loop with `return`, but not with `break`? Why?

Comment: after all I started thinking both is OK now. The reason i liked this is the use of `yield`. in second code fragment the for loop looks nice and very readable

Comment: @WolframH: You have a good point. The generator _is_ basically the same as using a break in the while loop. It's also a little less efficient.

Answer (score 7):

Python has an [alternative `iter` signature](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#iter) which takes function as the first argument and sentinel determining the stop condition as the second.

Using it, you can come up with something like this:

```
for s,img in iter(cv.read, (False, None)):
    print img
```

Still, I doubt if it is better than just plain `break` in the `if` block.

Also, it only accepts sentinel as the overall returned value, and can't base stop condition on some part of it (e.g. on the first value of the tuple). This can be workaround, but will make the code even more obfuscated:

```
>>> for s,img in itertools.takewhile(lambda x: x[0], iter(cv.read, None)):
    print img
```

It uses [`itertools.takewhile`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile) to determine when the first value of the returned tuple equals to `False`.

---

Full version for testing:

```
>>> class Capture(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.L = iter([1,2,3,4,5])
    def read(self):
        try:
            img = self.L.next()
        except StopIteration:
            return (False,None)
        return True, img

>>> cv = Capture()
>>> for s,img in iter(cv.read, (False, None)):
    print img

1
2
3
4
5

>>> cv = Capture()
>>> for s,img in itertools.takewhile(lambda x: x[0], iter(cv.read, None)):
    print img


1
2
3
4
5
```

Comment: @HayriUğurKoltuk Yeah, definitely. I would go with plain `if-brake`.

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
while capture.read()[0]: 
    #do something
```

Of course you won't be able to access the frame that way!!

There is another way

```
s,v = capture.read()
while s:
    #Do sth
    s,v = capture.read()
```

Which of course is a long-ish way of saying

```
while True: 
    s,v = capture.read()
    if not s: 
        break
```

Which (for some reason) you don't want to do

Comment: if read is a function, it probably will crash since you don't call it

Comment: "Which (for some reason) you don't want to do" I prefer checking the while condition in `while` itself, not somewhere else. i think that's why we have a condition after `while` keyword. but if in python the proper way is the use `if` inside a infinite loop, then i am afraid i will have to use it. i just don't feel right about it...

Comment: Ah! but your if _is_ inside the while. Anyways you can use my second option, or use ornoone's answer.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot do what you are asking in python (unless there are hacks i don't know about).

what the line:

```
s, i = capture.read()
```

is doing is assigning 2 separate variables by unpacking a tuple, there is just no way to tell python that you want the first assigned variable.
It is also illegal in python to assign within an `if`, `for` or `while` conditional statement.

the only thing you could do would be:

```
if(capture.read()[0]):
```

Which would mean you lose the image data.
In short, unpacking tuples is actually quite sexy, there's no reason to not take advantage of the functionality it provides!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution on who to break loop using function which return tuple.

```
>>> def read(a):
...     if a == 0:
...         return (False, a+1)
...     return (True, a-1)
... 
>>> read(5)
(True, 4)
>>> read(0)
(False, 1)
>>> a = True
>>> i = 5
>>> while(a):
...     a, i = read(i)
...     if a:
...         print 'working'
...         
...     
... 
working
working
working
working
working
>>>
```

Now your code will look like this:

```
s = True
while(s):
    s, i = capture.read()
```